# IllegalMonitorStateException on awaitTermination function

Tags: java, multithreading, illegalmonitorstateexcep

I'm having a problem with using threads in Java (I have little experience with threads in Java, but much in C++, so i understand basic concept of threads). I've used example code for threads in Java, and the code is next:

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(machines.size());

        for (Machine m : machines) {
            Runnable worker = new restartMachine(m.dataformachine());
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

`restartMachine()` is restarting some remote machines, and machines are not connected in any way, data that are being passed to Runnable are IP address for given machine, and command that are executing then locally on that machine.

Error that I'm getting on execution of this piece of code is next:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260)
 at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:460)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1471)
```

Exception is thrown on calling of function awaitTermination() from code above. As I understand, and from various examples that I've seen there shouldn't be any problems with this code.

```
public boolean awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException {
    long nanos = unit.toNanos(timeout);
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        for (;;) {
            if (runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), TERMINATED))
                return true;
            if (nanos <= 0)
                return false;
            nanos = termination.awaitNanos(nanos);
        }
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Trace indicate that error is in calling of function mainLock.unlock();
but as I understand it only main thread is going to execute that line, so I don't know why am I getting IllegalMonitorStateException, and there is no other code regarding threads in program (so I'm basically only using code from library)

I would appreciate any help, I know that there are many questions already answered regarding this problem (this exception), but I don't know what is the problem here.

Comment: Strange indeed.  What Java version?

Comment: Probably you want to share with us restartMachine code.

Comment: how is `termination` instantiated?

Comment: More information is needed here. The Java version (as VGR mentioned), but also: Is the error reproducable? (If so, why not post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?)

Comment: This seems like some sort of a bug manifesting in the VM.  If you can make this reproducable that would help.  Also, you should supply 1. Version of Java to the patch level, 2. Operating system 3. 32 or 64 bit  4. Any runtime args set.

Comment: Andremoniy raises a good point worth turning your investigation to first.

Comment: I'm using java 1.7.0_55 version, on 64 bit SUSE Linux, and no runtime arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This problem could be easily reproduced, if we will wrap your code inside some `Thread` and then call on him **deprecated** (just for demonstrating problem) method `stop`, e.g.:

```
  private void method() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10000L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                executor.shutdown();

                try {
                    executor.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        thread.stop();
    }
```

Running this code, we always get "desired" exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1260)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1471)
    at q29431344.TestThreads$1.run(TestThreads.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**What does it mean?**

Without viewing full project code (of course, we are not asking it), hard to say with 100% waranty what did happened. But there are 2 possibilities:

1) Your `restartMachine` class has stopped machine on which this application was running itself. This caused to `JVM` stopping with such sequel

2) Some where in your application you run mentioned code in other thread, which somewhere was stopped in way which I have described or another one.

So, you have to analyze these ways and understand what could be more similiar to your situation.

**UPD**: Just another idea, 3) if you are running your application under `Tomcat` for example, this also can lead to such problem when `Tomcat` stops your application.

Comment: I am not convinced a Thread.stop can result in an `IllegalMonitorStateException` like shown here.  It's possible, but I don't see how a thread still running can result in a IMSE when another thread is `stop`ed.  It should be pretty easy to prove if it's possible.

Comment: @JohnVint I can give you 100% warranty that if you will run this code, you will get `IllegalMonitorStateException`. It is always reproduceable.

Comment: I don't necessarily not believe you, but the code you're showing isn't complete enough for me to run.  Where is the ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: @JohnVint you have to replace comment ` your piece of code from question here` with code from question. I will update my answer for easy reproduce

Comment: Thanks.  So that's certainly a possibility.  Guess we'll have to see more from the OP if there is an actual stop invocation on container side

Comment: @JohnVint Ok, thanks. Just updated my code, made it more compact for problem reproducing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74427/discussion-between-andremoniy-and-john-vint).

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I don't think the problem is in any of 3 suggestion.

Comment: restartMachines connects to (distinct) remote machines, and than is executing commands on that machines (machines are not supporting java), so from java point of view restartMachines are just sending commands and printing output of results that machines are sending back (after specific commands being executed)

Answer (score 2):

This is very peculiar, and probably not your fault:

The Javadoc of ReentrantLock.unlock says:

> throws IllegalMonitorStateException if the current thread does not hold this lock

but the implementation of `awaitTermination` you have posted shows that the thread has successfully locked the very same object (through the final variable `mainLock`) previously. Therefore, there has been an intermediary unlock, or the ReentrantLock implementation has a bug (in its Java code, or native code, or possibly even the hard). Further analysis is necessary to discover which is the case. As you are currently the only one to be able to reproduce the problem, you are the only one that can perform that analysis effectively.

A reasonable first step would be to launch the application in debug mode, and set a breakpoint in `AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.setExclusiveOwnerThread` to verify whether there has been an intermediary unlock (and if so, from where). Should the presence of the breakpoint cause the problem to disappear (because it is timing sensitive), you might use a conditional breakpoint that never halts, but whose condition logs to System.out for your inspection, instead.

**Update**
Thanks to the reproducer provided by Andremoniy in his answer, I was able to perform this analysis myself. I used the following expression in the conditional breakpoint to obtain the stack trace whenever the lock is aquired or released:

```
new RuntimeException(this + " is now owned by " + arg0).printStackTrace();
return false;
```

Here is relevant part of the log output for his code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@a5e3519[State = 1, empty queue] is now owned by null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.setExclusiveOwnerThread(AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.java:74)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:155)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.fullyRelease(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1723)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2069)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1465)
    at stackoverflow.Test$1.run(Test.java:24)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

...

java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@a5e3519[State = 0, empty queue] could not be released, as it is owned by null rather than Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
```

That is, the executor has released, but not reacquired, `mainLock` in `awaitNanos`, which is implemented as follows:

```
    public final long awaitNanos(long nanosTimeout)
            throws InterruptedException {
        if (Thread.interrupted())
            throw new InterruptedException();
        Node node = addConditionWaiter();
        int savedState = fullyRelease(node);
        final long deadline = System.nanoTime() + nanosTimeout;
        int interruptMode = 0;
        while (!isOnSyncQueue(node)) {
            if (nanosTimeout <= 0L) {
                transferAfterCancelledWait(node);
                break;
            }
            if (nanosTimeout >= spinForTimeoutThreshold)
                LockSupport.parkNanos(this, nanosTimeout);
            if ((interruptMode = checkInterruptWhileWaiting(node)) != 0)
                break;
            nanosTimeout = deadline - System.nanoTime();
        }
        if (acquireQueued(node, savedState) && interruptMode != THROW_IE)
            interruptMode = REINTERRUPT;
        if (node.nextWaiter != null)
            unlinkCancelledWaiters();
        if (interruptMode != 0)
            reportInterruptAfterWait(interruptMode);
        return deadline - System.nanoTime();
    }
```

As we can see from the absence of a finally block, the method is not exception safe, i.e. the lock not reacquired when an exception is thrown (such as the `ThreadDeathException` caused by `Thread.stop()`).

You might wish to report this bug to Oracle. However, since it only appears to manifest upon use of a deprecated api, and the impact is rather minor (wrong exception type is thrown), they might not fix it.

Comment: It seems to me, that it is not needed. Such problem could be easily reproduced with simple `thread` killing. See my answer where I demonstrate such behaviour.

Comment: Even if Thread.stop() causes this behaviour, this still indicates that the handling of the locks is not exception safe, i.e. a bug in the JDK.

Comment: I don't think that it is `jvm` bug. Such behaviour is often seen when `Tomcat` is stopping, it seems that it kills threads with such rough way

Comment: that's cool analysis, but it seems that it practically useless for question author. And BTW, `+1` would be best `thanks` for `Andremoniy` :)